# Wrap text and other elements separately in a td tag

Tags: html, css

I have a td assuming in the below representation `[x]` as a checkbox and the text is labelled next to it, if I display the label inline it appears like in Rep1, but I want it to look as displayed below like in Rep 2:

`**Rep 1 :
[x]  long command looks
like this which is odd
**Rep 2:
[x]  would look better if
     it lined up like this`

Any suggestions on the easiest way to do this?

Comment: please post your html

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using:

1) tables:2 columns

2) float left/right in a div

3) making a text box with the text and positioning it around the td

*but*
You said that you got both in a td so using float with the checkbox and the div with the text in my opinion is a good solution